# Handling undefined keys in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Is it possible to set a handler for undefined keys in Core Data?

I'm asking because despite defining `valueForUndefinedKey:` my implementation of that method is never called if `valueForKey:` is invoked on a managed object that doesn't have an attribute with that key.

This is needed for a synchronization system I'm currently writing where an object can be marked as `locallyCreated` or `locallyDeleted` but at the same time not all objects are editable so I want to avoid defining these properties for all entities in my model (around ~25 entities).

Although it seems tempting to create a single parent entity for that purpose I would like to avoid doing that since that will put all objects in one giant SQLite table which as far as I know will have negative impact on performance.

Currently I have a base "entity" class called `RemoteObject` that defines some common attributes like `remoteID`, `locallyCreated`, `locallyDeleted`, as suggested in another answer on SO, which all other entities inherit in code like this:

```
@interface RemoteObject : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *remoteID;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL locallyCreated;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL locallyDeleted;

@end

@implementation RemoteObject

@dynamic remoteID;
@dynamic locallyCreated;
@dynamic locallyDeleted;

@end

@interface Project : RemoteObject

// custom properties

@end
```

What I want is to inspect any given `RemoteObjet` and see if it was locally create or deleted. However, as I said above, not all of the entities have corresponding attributes, so Core Data will throw an exception.

I found a workaround that allows me to avoid those errors - define a class method instead:

```
- (id)valueForKeyIfExists:(NSString *)key {
    if (self.entity.attributesByName[key] != nil) {
        return [self valueForKey:key];
    }
    return nil;
}

+ (BOOL)objectIsLocallyCreated:(RemoteObject *)object {
    return [[object valueForKeyIfExists:@"locallyCreated"] boolValue];
}
```

But I was wondering if it would be possible to refactor this into object properties instead, catching undefined keys with `valueForUndefinedKey:` like this:

```
- (id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
    if ([key isEqualToString:LocallyCreatedKey]
        || [key isEqualToString:LocallyDeletedKey]) {
        return @(NO);
    }
    return [super valueForUndefinedKey:key];
}

- (BOOL)locallyDeleted {
    return [[self valueForKey:LocallyDeletedKey] boolValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to move those 2 flag attributes into a different class and then anything which doesn't have them is a subclass of `RemoteObject` and anything which does is a subclass of the new class, perhaps `TrackedRemoteObject`. Then in your algorithm you can class test to determine conformance.